# Firefox is not opening `.mov` video files: “Video format or mime type is not supported.”

Tags: firefox, video

I want to open `.mov` files from Firefox in VLC.

On my `Options/Applications` there is no item in the list for `mov` or video.

The firefox help says "click on the mov file and select the application".
When I click on a `.mov` file, it goes straight to a grey screen with a video icon, and the message:

> Video format or mime type is not supported.

Firefox does **not** ask what to do with it, even though everything in `settings/applications` is set to `always ask`. In `options/general/downloads`, I have checked `Always ask you where to save files`. If I right-click a `.mov` and use `save link as...`, I can save the file and open it in VLC, no problem.

I'm using Windows 7, if that matters. In the firefox console, I see

```
Media resource http://.../09312-s2.mov could not be decoded.
```

And if this is relevant, the server header is `Content-Type: "video/quicktime"`

Answer (score 0):

Check under Settings in the Applications panel how Firefox handles mov files:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/applications-panel-set-how-firefox-handles-files

The MIME types available in Firefox are AFAIK based off of the MIME types registered in Windows. If there is a MIME type that isn't showing up, make sure that it is setup properly in Windows. For more clues on adding a new mime type look [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1706945).